# Executing block inside another block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Definition:

`NSDictionary * (^blockThatReturnsADict)(void)`

Implementation:

```
blockThatReturnsADict block = ^NSDictionary *(void) {

    [SomeClass fetchADictionaryForKey:@"key" onSuccess:^(NSDictionary* dict) {
        //how do i return dict from here?
    }];

}
```

Is this a use case where it would be logical to rethink the design?

*UPDATE*

The 'fetchADictionaryForKey' block is asynchronous. So I think I cannot just declare a block variable, and return it.

Comment: Presumably the block is asynchronous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the standard class of problems that futures and promises would solve, so you have two high-level options:

1) Adopt a promise library or framework and use promises everywhere, assuming you have a need for a lot of sequential asynchronous blocks.

OR

2) If you don't have that many, then use the same mechanism iOS generally uses: success callbacks.

For your case here, the easy way out is probably #2.  Pass in a success block (instead of void) and then invoke the success block with your result in your inner block.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will using a success block will be a cleaner implementation in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return results from an asynchronous block (because you obviously can't). The asynchronous block sets the result in the appropriate place. For example, your object may have a property resultDict, and the callback just says

```
self.resultDict = dict;
```